# Finding the nth derivative of $y=e^{ax+b}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How to find the $n$-th derivative of $y=e^{ax+b}$

Please provide an explanation of the steps.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall that for $y = e^{f(x)},\; y' = f'(x)e^{f(x)}$, where $f(x)$ is a function of $x$. This is making use of the chain rule, as it relates to the exponential function.

$\;y' = a \,e^{ax + b}$

$\,y'' = a^2 e^{ax + b}$

$y''' = a^3 e^{ax + b}$

$\vdots$

$y^{(n)} = a^n e^{ax + b}$.

Comment: why powers of a is added on front of e^(ax+b) in every steps ?

Comment: @Rahul Sharma Chain rule

Comment: @RahulSharma: First line.

Comment: Okay... Thank you,,..got it after reading chain rule.

Comment: See my added note. We need to find $d/dx(e^{f(x)}) = f'(x)e^{f(x)}$. In this case, $f(x) = ax + b$, so $f'(x) = a$. Each time we take the derivative, we need to multiply the previous derivative by $(ax + b)' = a$. Doing that $n$ times gives us $$\underbrace{a \cdot a \cdot \cdots a}_{\large n \;\text{times}}\,e^{f(x)}$$

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much for helping out.

Comment: You're welcome, Rahul!

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)=e^{ax+b}$, then

$$
\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{d(ax+b)}{dx}e^{ax+b} = ae^{ax+b}
$$

$$
\frac{df^2}{dx^2} = \frac{d(ax+b)}{dx}ae^{ax+b} = a^2e^{ax+b}
$$

$$
...
$$

$$
\frac{df^n}{dx^n} = \frac{d(ax+b)}{dx}a^{n-1}e^{ax+b} = a^ne^{ax+b}
$$